# DynamoDB: High SuccessfulRequestLatency

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, latency

We had a period of latency in our application that was directly correlated with latency in DynamoDB and we are trying to figure out what caused that latency.

During that time, the consumed reads and consumed writes for the table were normal (much below the provisioned capacity) and the number of throttled requests was also 0 or 1. The only thing that increased was the SuccessfulRequestLatency.

The high latency occurred during a period where we were doing a lot of automatic writes. In our use case, writing to dynamo also includes some reading (to get any existing records). However, we often write the same quantity of data in the same period of time without causing any increased latency.

Is there any way to understand what contributes to an increase in SuccessfulRequest latency where it seems that we have provisioned enough read capacity? Is there any way to diagnose the latency caused by this set of writes to dynamodb?

Answer (score 1):

You can dig deeper by checking the **Get Latency** and **Put Latency** in CloudWatch.

As you have already mentioned, there was no throttling, and your writes involve some reading as well, and your writes at other period of time don't cause any latency, you should check for what exactly in *read* operation is causing this.

Check `SuccessfulRequestLatency` metric while including the `Operation` dimension as well. Start with `GetItem` and `BatchGetItem`. If that doesn't 
help include `Scan` and `Query` as well.

Answer (score 1):

High request latency can sometimes happen when DynamoDB is doing an internal failover of one of its storage nodes.

Internally within Dynamo each storage partition has to be replicated across multiple nodes to provide a high level of fault tolerance. Occasionally one of those nodes will fail and a replacement node has to be introduced, and this can result in elevated latency for a subset of affected requests.

The advice I've had from AWS is to use a short timeout and a fast retry (e.g. 100ms) if your use-case is latency-sensitive.  It's my understanding that only requests that hit the affected node experience increased latency, so within one or two retries you'll hit a different node and get a successful response, with minimal impact on your overall latency. Obviously it's hard to verify this, because it's not a scenario you can reproduce!

If you've got a support contract with AWS, it's well worth submitting a support ticket from the AWS console when events like this happen. They are usually able to provide an insight into what actually happened.

Note: If you're doing retries, remember to use exponential backoff to reduce the risk of throttling.